# Can't get right DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, xamarin, .net-5, cultureinfo

I'm trying to get the correct spanish datetime.

I have this code and I get the following DateTime : 19/05/2022 8:43 and it is off by 2 hours. What I want to get is 19/05/2022 10:43. I have been searching how to do this but nothing has worked.

Here is my code

```
 string dateString = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();
            DateTimeFormatInfo date = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
            date.ShortDatePattern = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM TT";
            DateTime resultDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dateString, date).ToLocalTime();
```

How can I do this?

**EDIT**

Trying this I still get two hours less

```
var utcDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
            var localDateTime = utcDateTime.ToLocalTime().ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm tt");
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why all this transformation? Just do `DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime().ToString()` ?

Comment: BTW : `HH:MM` would be Hours:Month. Use `HH:mm`.

Comment: So, do you simply want to add two hours? Does "DateTime.UtcNow" produce an incorrect time? Or does your parsing code not handle time zones correctly?  And why not use `DateTime.Parse`? I would expect `DateTime.Parse(myDateTime.ToString())` to produce the original datetime, is this not the case?

Comment: @JonasH I have tried this along with DateTime.Parse it just gets the wrong hour

Comment: @robluc parsing will get the right time. The datetime object just won't know if it is utc or localtime. if you get the utc part it `.ToUniversalTime()` will substact the local time offset to utc and `.ToLocalTime()` will add it. so leave out the `.ToLocalTime()` and parse the string directly and it should work. If you just want the datetime as string use `DateTime.Now`

Comment: Cannot reproduce. A little sample App resulted: "Culture set to: es UTC : 05/19/2022 9:14 a. m. LOC : 05/19/2022 11:14 a. m." with `utc.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm tt")` without exceptions and expected times...

Comment: @Mucksh So what you said works. The issue was that the emulator was not in the correct time zone

Comment: The easiest way would be doing `string dateString = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm tt");`. If you need to work with UTC and display that DateTime in a specific timezone you can check the documentation [Converting UTC to a designated time zone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/converting-between-time-zones#converting-utc-to-a-designated-time-zone)

Comment: @Cleptus I will try and implement that. Thank you!

Comment: @robluc de nada ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you may simply do this

```
var utcDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
var localDateTime = utcDateTime.ToLocalTime().ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm tt");
```

Comment: @OP: You may want to check if your current locale is actually set to spanish locale.

Comment: Check Fildor comment on question.. I believe he's right and you should use `HH:mm` instead of `HH:MM`

Comment: ^^ and "tt" instead of "TT" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: @PaulKaram If I use HH:mm it will give me an exception

Comment: Then please post an [mcve].

Comment: This code will give me the following error: **System.FormatException:** 'Format_UnknownDateTimeWord'

Comment: @HarshRaj still gets to hour less than the actual time. I will edit my post and show it